# What does ": exit 0" mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I found in some bash scripts, usually at the end of the file, there is one line of code, like below:

```
: exit 0
```

What's the meaning of it? Can I remove it directly?

Comment: `:` is an alias for `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash` builtin `:` is basically a command that returns zero (success) after all its arguments are expanded by the shell<sup>(a)</sup>. In this case, the expansion doesn't really do anything so it's effectively a null operation. I suspect it's there just to indicate the *effect* of the `:`<sup>(b)</sup>.

And the effect of that `:` has to do with what `bash` scripts return. They basically return the exit status of the last command that was run in the script. The `:` will therefore force the exit status of the script as a whole to be zero *regardless* of what the command before it returned.

You can see the effect with the following script:

```
ls /tmp/nosuchfile 2> /dev/null
```

If you run that followed by `echo $?`, you'll see an error code:

```
pax> ./script.sh ; echo $?
2
```

If you then change the script to:

```
ls /tmp/nosuchfile 2> /dev/null
: some arbitrary text
```

then you will see a success code from the script:

```
pax> ./script.sh ; echo $?
0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I often use it for infinite loops, such as:

```
while : ; do somePeriodicThing ; sleep 60 ; done
```

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Of course, it's not *quite* the same as `exit 0` since the `exit` will exit your current shell which will act differently depending on whether you ran it or sourced it:

```
./script.sh    # runs it, exit will exit that script.
. ./script.sh  # sources it, exit will exit your shell.
```

The `:` will not exit your current shell in either of those two cases.

Comment: ":" command makes me confused, can you point out the definition or explanation of  this command? I don't find any useful info after searched by google :(

Comment: What is there to be confused about, @windxlnx?  It is a command that succeeds, returning status 0. It is like `true` except `true` is used without arguments, whereas `:` has them. In the original Unix Version 7 Bourne shell, there was no comment convention (neither shebangs `#!/bin/sh` nor '`#`-starts-a-comment' were supported), so Bourne shell scripts started with a `:` often followed by a single quoted string that described what the script did. The C shell used to look at the start of a command and if it began with a `:`, it would run the Bourne shell rather than the C shell to interpret it.

Comment: @windxlnx, you can find out about the `:` command (and others) with `man bash-builtins`.

Comment: @windxlnx See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html